# Determine if a modal view controller is being shown

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller

Is there anyway to determine if a modal view controller is currently being shown? currently on view?

I have an issue where a viewDidAppear is being called twice and only needs to be called once, to resolve I would like to see if a modal view controller is on the screen if it is run one bit of code, else nothing.

It would be useful if I could code inside the current view controller on the navigation stack, and see if a modal view controller is on top of that at the present time?

Comment: Can't you just keep track of when you show/hide your modal view controller with a bool property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct place to check on the wellbeing of a modal viewController, is in it's presenting viewController. The presenting viewController ought to know whether its presented viewController is still present, or has been dismissed (it is responsible for both tasks). The presentingViewController has a property, `presentedViewController` which carries the reference you need.

If the modal VC has been covered up, for example by itself pushing another viewController, you would be able to ascertain that from it's navController.viewControllers array property: again, the best reference source goes back to the presenting viewController.

If you can't get a reference to the modal viewController from it's presenting viewController, there is probably is something wrong with your design, you need to rethink.

Answer (score 0):

If "`viewDidAppear`" is being called twice, it may be that you are instantiating (creating) your view twice.

Set a breakpoint in "`viewDidAppear`" and look at the backtrace to see if your new view controller is being created programatically (in code) or from being instantiated in your XIB or Storyboard.

You only need to create it once, and if you create it only once, "`viewDidAppear`" will be called only once.

Comment: p.s. are you talking about *modal* views or just regular views?? Before Valentin did his edit, you were talking about "model view controllers" (which is a design pattern) and I suspect you were just talking about a regular view.  But then @sooper mentioned "modal" and I think that's what inspired Valentin to do his edit.

Comment: I think he's talking about pulling up a VC for the first time, getting `viewDidAppear`, presenting a second controller as a modal, dismissing that modal, and getting `viewDidAppear` again on the first controller when its view reappears. This is standard operating procedure.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks both, What happens is a i load a VC at the start, it checks if a user is logged in if not presents a model VC for login. What I am seeing is the viewDidAppear on the original (first) VC being called twice. You are correct, ideally I would not want this being called twice, I am unsure if this is normal. If this is something I can backtrace with a breakpoint, how do i determine from the stop in code where the callback occurs from?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something in `viewDidAppear` to execute once, there are a ton of ways of doing it, but here's one. First, define class property:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL alreadyRun;
```

Then in `viewDidAppear`, check that property:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (!self.alreadyRun)
    {
        self.alreadyRun = YES;

        // do whatever you need to have done once per instance of this VC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the PresendedViewController property. earlier versions it was modalViewController.